# ООП, parent или прямой вызов

Tags: ооп, php

```
class core {
  public static function с() {}
}

class controller_admin extends core {
  echo parent::c();
}
```

или

```
class core {
  public static function с() {}
}

class controller_admin{
  echo core::c();
}
```

Как правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

правильней через parent ибо если вы перенесете класс в другой проект, и наследуемый класс сменит название будет ошибка и придется во всем классе менять вызов. опять таки если метод "с" больше не должен быть статическим, снова будет ошибка.

Comment: Во общем никакой разницы.